# Can I connect VM to Wamp installation of Mysql running on same machine?

Tags: database, virtual-machines, database-connection

On my Windows 7 PC I have Virtual Box running a Centos VM that has PHP installed on it but no MySQL that I brought from the office.

I am trying to set up a database for it. I have Wamp installed on my PC and tried to connect to that database, but I couldn't get it working (I'm thinking since localhost on my PC would not necessarily be visible to the VM). Is there anything I can do to connect to that from a VM or is there a simpler solution to get a MySQL database set up that the VM can connect to?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on where you're trying to set-up that database?  Is that inside the VM, or on the host OS? WAMP should come with MySQL, so I don't see why you want to jump through hoops.

Comment: Wamp is on the host OS (VM is linux which i am very unfamiliar with).

Comment: I posted this here because I put it on SO and was told it belonged here. Really dislike it when a question gets closed with no comments.

Answer (score 1):

To install MySQL and other needed packages on CentOS (doesn't matter if it's a VM or physical), all you have to do is run

```
sudo yum install mysql-server php-mysql
```

This will install MySQL server and a php library to talk to it and any missing dependencies for it.

Comment: noice. i kind of want to keep mysql separate from the VM .. is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: If you still want to keep MySQL on your host machine, then 1st you need to make sure that your VM is allowed to communicate over network with your host. Next you need to make sure that your MySQL/WAMP is configured to listen on your LAN IP and not just on 'localhost'.